NGINX uri encoding problem, can't match a map of uri's with request uri
I have a nginx map of a bunch of uri's that I want to redirect to another uri. The problem is some of them uri's has uri encoded chars like %20 or %29. Now what's going on is that nginx gives me the request uri but its uri decoded meaning for example its giving me "/blogpost/november twentysixth" instead of "/blogpost/november%20twentysixth" which is needed to match the uri in the map.
I have a total of 53k uri's to redirect so don't say we should just do location ... with every single uri.
I tried to rewrite the url to filter out the whitespace etc but that caused problems because I then had duplicated uris. (Causing nginx to not start anymore and returning an error)
I tried to implement Lua but probably not the right way or it just didn't work.

I don't understand what your question is. If you use $request_uri in your map you will need to match against strings with %20 for spaces. If you use $uri in your map you will need to match against strings with embedded spaces and these will need to be enclosed within quotes. Both schemes work as long as you understand the differences. If you are having issues, edit your question and provide an example map and extracts from the access log.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
